# Can we be accurate about how many moderator candidates there are?

Tags: feature-request, election, nominations, numbers, moderator-primaries

Browsing over to the 2012 SO moderator election (currently in the election phase), the sidebar at the top says:

> #### moderator candidates
> 18

but then there are only **10** candidates listed.

I realize that this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign); only the top ten candidates from the primaries advance to the election stage, but the wording makes it sound like something funny is going on.  I was worried for a moment that some of the candidates tagged their statements with one of my ignored tags.

**In the spirit of accuracy, could we either change the heading to "*initial moderator candidates*", or the number to "*10*" for the elections stage?**

Comment: This is not how you run a shadow government

Comment: Related: (1) [Completed elections don't show all candidates in the primary phase](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286859); (2) [Candidates not surviving primaries not displayed in "primary" tab anymore for past elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170912).

Comment: @random as the shadow, I agree. ;)