# Candidates not surviving primaries not displayed in "primary" tab anymore for past elections

Tags: bug, election, moderator-primaries

https://stackoverflow.com/election/3?tab=primary

There are 18 candidates but only the 10 candidates who survived the primaries are listed there. I think the other candidates should also be shown in this tab - they were part of the primary voting after all.

Comment: I tried to view other candidates' votes but it is not available.

Comment: You can view it in the nomination tab though (though you won't see the votes for those who didn't make it into the election phase)

Comment: I thought [this was fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102260/election-primaries-appear-to-perpetually-check-the-candidate-reputation) - odd.