# Completed elections don't show all candidates in the primary phase

Tags: bug, election, moderator-primaries

On [the primary tab of completed elections](https://stackoverflow.com/election/7?tab=primary), only the top 10-finishing candidates are shown. This should be changed to show the primary as it was run, with all candidates (up to 30).

Only the election phase should cut off candidates who didn't pass the primary.

Comment: Worth to mention that it [does show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x51Aj.png) "19 Candidates" in the title, so even more confusing. (feel free to use the screenshot in the bug report :))

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard It now shows "18 Candidates" for me (in fact, a few minutes ago I'm pretty sure it was showing me "17 Candidates", too). It seems that there is a regression of the bug marked (status-completed) here: [Election primaries appear to perpetually check the candidate reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102260). Probably this bug has been around for a while, since there's a much older bug report that looks like a duplicate of this one: [Candidates not surviving primaries not displayed in "primary" tab anymore for past elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/170912).

Comment: @TheAmplitwist more likely it's a case of deleted account.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Ah, you're probably right.

Answer (score 5):

If you're after the primary scores, you can use the Data Explorer as a workaround.

```
select Id as [Post Link], OwnerUserId as [User Link], Score, CreationDate, Body
from Posts where PostTypeId = 6
order by CreationDate
```

[Results here for Stack Overflow.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/576564) Entries with a Score of zero didn't make it to the primary (or actually got a net score of zero there, but that's probably not common). The Post Link column takes you to the nomination, if it wasn't removed. To see only people who passed the nomination phase, tack on a `and Score <> 0` to the "where" part.